# How can I make 'require(packageName)' read multiple module paths besides 'node_modules'?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I've got an old project on my hands which uses *cortex* and *gulp* to construct the code.

Cortex is a package tool, kind of like npm, but it puts the packages under its own directory called **neurons**, not **node_modules**. As the code scales and becomes larger, I want to use webpack's hot loader in the dev environment. But when I run webpack, require can't find packages that are installed by cortex because it always tries to locate them in the **node_modules** folder instead of the **neurons** folder.

(The packages are very old, I can't even find them in the npm, which means I have to use cortex's packages)

Is there any way to make the require function read different paths?

Comment: couldn't you just go a directory above the environment your working in? ../? Or am I that tired?

Comment: my question is ,can I make the require(packageName) read the path that is in the neurons? the path parmeters of require is  a package name.not a relative path or else.

Comment: What is the actual directory the neurons are located in? What about https://www.npmjs.com/package/cortex-bundle ?

Comment: I think the package folder is a prop on the require somewhere. It's not meant to be changed I suppose, but maybe you can add another path there. Log the structure of require to see where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set it in your `webpack.config.js` like this:

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.resolve('./neurons'),
    'node_modules'
  ]
}
```

The modules option defaults to: `modules: ["node_modules"]`, so that's why it can't find your cortex packages.

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestions. You remind me of  my high school english teacher.